# In an Angular directive, how do you reapply an event listener after the event has been removed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This might be a result of me lacking knowledge in Angular and if so, forgive me in advance if that is the case.

In Angular, suppose I have a directive which is bound to an element as an attribute.

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

In the directive, I have a click event which will remove the click event itself.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
   return {
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
          ele.on("click", function() {
              ele.off("click");
              console.log("Click event removed");
          });
      }
   }
});
```

I want to set the click event on to the same div from this directive again (let's say after a button is clicked).  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of removing the click, use a variable to store the state and perform the actions based on the state of the variable.

Comment: @Sherin Mathew I figured it would come down to doing something like that.  But I still want to know if it is possible to reapply the event or if it is completely gone once the .off() is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this-

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
   return {
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
          ele.on("click", function() {
              ele.unbind("click");
              console.log("Click event removed");

             angular.element(ele).bind("click");
          });

      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
   return {
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
          ele.on("click", function() {
              angular.element(ele).off('click');
              console.log("Click event removed");
          });
      }
   }

});
```